# does an angle of 0 degrees between 2 vectors mean they are linearly dependent

Tags: linear-algebra

If the angle between 2 vectors is 0 degrees or 180 degrees does that imply the 2 vectors are linear dependent?

Comment: Yes, by Cauchy Schwarz inequality as stated by chriseur. Graphically, an angle of 0° would imply that one is the scalar multiple of other, thus linearly dependent.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Use the equality condition for Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality.